# Use display:none, html

Tags: html

I´ve build a table and it looks like this:

```
total:
1402892
1402892
1402892
```

but I would like to show the Value only once. I tried it with display: none but it shows then nothing. how can I do this.

Comment: some actual markup of your attempt would provide some context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to add a class to the table row of the values that are identical? If so, you could try the following CSS:

```
.class:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}
```

Assuming .class is the name of the class on the table row.

Comment: no unfortunately, I tried it with this 'style="display:{group|2:none;3:none;|}"' but it not works

Comment: That definitely won't work. I've created a CodePen of my suggestion so you can see exactly what I mean. Take a look: http://codepen.io/noelslevin/pen/NGZgWx